# How to bypass current error in data tuple in send mass mail?

Tags: django, smtplib

I am working on a bulk mailing platform using Django `send_mass_mail` function. Everything worked perfectly. But the problem I am facing is, I have nearly 500 recipients, and if one recipient fails to receive mail (recipient side errors like, improper mail address provision), the whole function stops immediately. How to send the next mail, if current data tuple has errors in data. I think the question is straight and need no code examples. Since i followed straight from the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#send-mass-mail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#send-mass-mail) you could use `fail_silently=True` (which is `False` by default):

> `fail_silently`: A boolean. When it’s `False`, `send_mail()` will raise an `smtplib.SMTPException` if an error occurs. See the `smtplib` docs for a list of possible exceptions, all of which are subclasses of `SMTPException`.